# What is "if <> 6" in classic asp?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm reading a bit of asp code, and I can't figure out what `if <> (whatevernumber)` means.

Is `<>` equal to, or is it different from maybe? I can't Google this issue, as it doesn't search for symbols..

Comment: It means Not equal to, eg `!=` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"<>" is a comparison. You have to put a number or variable on each side. Like: "Hey computer! Compare x with z and tell me if they are not equal!" You would type it like this:

```
if (x<>z) then response.write ("hey x and z are not equal! Gimme ten dollars!")
```

Answer (score 1):

As given, the code fragment is a sytax error:

```
>> If <> 6
>>
Error Number:       1002
Error Description:  Syntax error
```

It's missing an operand to compare to and a `Then`. "<>" is the not equal to/different [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```
>> If 6 <> 6 Then WScript.Echo "different" : Else WScript.Echo "equal to" : End If
>>
equal to
>> If 7 <> 6 Then WScript.Echo "different" : Else WScript.Echo "equal to" : End If
>>
different
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer but I guess Ekkehard's lack of explanation has let him down.

Comment: @Lankymart - what explanation should I add to improve the answer?

Comment: It's an approach I see you use a lot, copy paste your own tests and expect people to understand them. That's OK for seasoned programmers but not everyone is going to understand the formats you post. *At this point I would like to point out that I up-voted your answer. +1*

Comment: @Lankymart - thanks, but what should I change/add to really deserve your upvote?

Comment: Nothing, your answer makes sense to me, my point is merely it might not to others. As the OP is asking about what the operator `<>` means it's a fair bet they are not a seasoned programmer and struggle to interpret your code tests.

Comment: No, I just asked specifically what the <> operand was. I just wanted to know if it meant "not equal to", or something else. That's all I was asking.